# C# application in Docker

Tags: c#, docker

I clicked "add Docker support" in VisualStudio and something has happened, but I don't understand what.

`docker images` lists a thing what seems to have been created.

When I run the application from VisualStudio for the first time a new entry appears in `docker ps`, but it stays there after the application exists and VisualStudio finishes debugging. So is VisualStudio not properly shutting down and tidying up after debugging?

If I `docker stop` but do not `docker rm` then VisualStudio will create another entry in `docker ps` when I run it again.

My C# application reads a file on my hard drive, but this doesn't work with Docker. However, it can access files *somewhere* -- for example `FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"ConsoleAppDocker.txt");` can read and write, and its contents are saved across runs, even if I (try to) clean up all the Docker things.

Here are the questions:

- Where is and how can I see the special Docker file that is being read/written? `f.FullName` is `C:\app\ConsoleAppDocker.txt` but the file has appeared in the directory of the `csproj`. This makes no sense.
- How can I read/write a normal file on my hard drive?
- If I write to the special Docker file and then `docker stop` and `docker rm` and `docker image rm` all the Dockers then the next time I run the application in VisualStudio the contents of the file are still there -- they have not been deleted. WTF?

Comment: I recommend you read up on what docker is and how it works. Basically (afaik) it creates a mini VM, with it's own filesystem. So your `C:\app\ConsoleAppDocker.txt` isn't on your hard disk directly, but inside the docker containers file system

Comment: Can you recommend something? I've found it all rather impenetrable, and the file being created in the project directory seems to be a complete contradiction.